# Is Microsoft .NET Framework Client Profile enough for PowerShell to work on a Windows XP workstation?

Tags: windows-xp, powershell, .net

Is Microsoft [.NET Framework Client Profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_3.5_SP1_Client_Profile) enough for PowerShell to work on a Windows XP workstation? Or is a full .NET version needed to be installed? Are there any advantages for the full version?

- PowerShell version: 2.0
- .NET version: ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [download page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929):

> Windows PowerShell 2.0 requires version 2.0 of the common language runtime (CLR). Cmdlets built for Windows PowerShell 2.0 must be compiled for CLR 2.0. CLR 2.0 is included with the Microsoft .NET Framework versions 2.0, 3.0, or 3.5 with Service Pack 1.

Comment: So what exactly is a Client Profile? where does it come in these things?

Comment: As far as I know, .Net 4.0 was the first version to have a separate client profile. [This MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/04/12/what-s-new-in-net-framework-4-client-profile-rtm.aspx) explains the differences in great detail. I don't think it's even possible to install the .Net 4.0 client profile on XP without any other frameworks, so it's a moot point, but I could be wrong.